# Laravel: access view composer's data in other file(s)

Tags: php, laravel, view

I have a view composer file called `statistics.blade.php` which is accessed on every page in the application(also included on the dashboard). On the `dashboard` page the same set of data is displayed in the form `tiles`.

```php
class StatisticsComposer
{
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        # models
        $ModelA  = new ModelA();
        $ModelB  = new ModelB();
        $ModelC  = new ModelC();

        ...

        # binding data
        $view->with('arrayStatistics', [
            'ModelA'  => $ModelA->_someMethod(),
            'ModelB'  => $ModelB->_someMethod(),
            'ModelC'  => $ModelC->_someMethod(),

            ...
        ]);
    }
}
```

I need to access this `arrayStatistics` array on the `dashboard` index file. Is it possible..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you created your `StatisticsComposer` then you need to `boot` it in service provider.

Create a service provider called `ComposerServiceProvider` such as ;

```
class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer(['statistics'], StatisticsComposer::class); // assuming it is in `resources` folder

        // other view composer bindings...
    }
}
```

and at it to app.php's `providers` array such as;

```
'providers' => [
     // ... other providers
     App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class,
],
```

Then `$arrayStatistics` will be accessible on your `statistics.blade`.

Edit:
I think it is better to not use `arrayStatistics` but `ModelA`, `ModelB` directly for direct usage/access.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. The `statistics` code is working fine on every page. However, instead of creating a separate `ServiceProvider` for it, I have been using it through `AppServiceProvider`. Is it necessary to be done via the suggested way, or is it fine the way it already is..?

Comment: @MrSingh If you have one or two(less) i think `AppServiceProvider` is enough, but we had 25 (180 LoC) so  we separated.

Comment: Ok, Thanks again. :)